# Form userControl panel overlapping

Tags: c#, winforms

I had two forms - form "main" and form "alert".

I've changed Form "alert" to userControl,

Here is the code in form "main".

```
alert = new AlertForm();
alert.TopLevel = false;
alert.Visible = true;
this.pnlData.Controls.Add(alert); 
alert.Canceled += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(buttonCancel_Click);
alert.Show();
```

pnlData is a panel inside the form "main"

When I try to run, the userControl is overlapping like this,

[image: Image1]

how to fix that?
how to bring userControl in front of the label and textbox in pnlData?

Comment: Note, that your "dialog" is just added as control (not a dialog/window!) to your pnlData control. Read the Remarks and Example section in the [Form documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about how to do it properly.

Comment: It is a simple Z-order problem.  Add `alert.BringToFont();`  Setting TopLevel = false is not a great idea here.

Comment: i try to remove `TopLevel` and add `alert.BringToFont();` but error `Top-level control cannot be added to a control.` @HansPassant

Comment: Do not do both.  If you don't assign TopLevel then don't call Controls.Add()

Comment: Your fix is simple: `control.BringToFront`. Make sure your alert is actually a `control`, not form

Comment: It looks like you adding a form, which still should be possible if `TopLevel` is set to false. try also set border to none

Comment: so What should i do ? @HansPassant

Comment: i add `myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` in my alert but still overlapping @T.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your problems. This is the code that got rid of it:

```
public Form1() // constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Form f = new Form2();
    f.TopLevel = false;
    panel1.Controls.Add(f);
    f.BringToFront();
    // Edit: if you want to change Top - do similar thing to Y
    f.Location = new Point((int)(panel1.Size.Width / 2 - f.Size.Width / 2), 0);
    f.Show();

}
```

Works perfect - form is moving inside panel

Comment: what do you want to center?

Comment: the form2, how to position form 2 center of screen

Comment: `f.Location = new Point((int)(panel1.Size.Width / 2 - f.Size.Width / 2), (panel1.Size.Height / 2 - f.Size.Height / 2));` now all works now , thanks a lot @T.S